# Giving info to a .cfm web page and retrieving results

Tags: android, web

I do not even know how to call what I want to do.

I'd like to write an Android application which connects to a website like the Google's advanced search, fill in some fields, launch the search and then retrieve the results from the website.

So if you know names of techs or tools that I have to use in order to achieve this... enlighten me :).

PS : I know Java and I have already written some Android app.

**EDIT : actually the webpage I want to use is like http://www.glossary.mycompany.com/mainsearch.cfm**

**http://www.glossary.mycompany.com/MainIndex.cfm?ID=1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websites like the Google Advanced Search give parameters in the URL in order to process the info a user puts in. Maybe you could use the same for your app, using a Stringbuilder to build the entire URL including your parameters, then starting an Intent / WebView with your that URL.

Comment: Thx, Your answer made me check what was the URL. Unfortunately the question still remains.